# SQL: Need help creating a one-to-many Set comparing query

Tags: sql, database, set, one-to-many

The parameters are thus:

1. I have a table called Tasks with columns ID (primary key) and label (text).
2. I have another table called Locations with a foreign key referencing Tasks' ID and a name for a location (text).
3. In my code I have a set of locations.
4. UPDATED: I need a query to return all tasks that have associated locations found within my set.  Each task that has an associated location not found in my set must be thrown out.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass a set (a.k.a. a table) from you client application to your SQL DBMS? There are many approaches to this problem (multiple scalar parameters, a delimited string, XML, etc) and is largely dependent on the SQL product in question. You will find lots of questions on SO about this :)

Comment: No, I just needed a bit of help with the query logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the modified requirement:

```
select * from tasks t
where exists (select null from locations l
              where t.id = l.task_id and l.name in ('London', 'Geneva'...)) and
  not exists (select null from locations l
              where t.id = l.task_id and l.name not in ('London', 'Geneva'...))
```

Comment: I think this might work.  I also earlier finally managed to come up with:
SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT UNIQUE L.taskid FROM Locations L WHERE L.val NOT IN ('London', 'Geneva', ...));  I'm not sure if mine is correct, though.